# How to allow an email-address in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Now emails from a email-address gets into my junk e-mail folder. I would like to have it into my inbox instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Outlook 2010, under the `Home` tab, in the `Move` group, there is a drop-down button called `Rules`.  Click this button and select `Create Rule...`.  Several options are available for rule creation, if you don't see the option you want, click on the `Advanced Options` button for even more options and fine grain tuning of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Outlook 2010, a simpler solution might be to right-click on the mail in question and choose one of:

1. Junk Mail > Never Block Sender
2. Junk Mail > Never Block Sender's Domain
3. Junk Mail > Never Block this Group or Mailing List

or while the mail is still in the Junk Mail folder

4. Junk Mail > Not Junk

It takes all of 5 seconds.